# When to use Aside vs Section or something else for a Filter in HTML5

Tags: html

I am doing a search results page with a filter by type of content. For example, something link this:

```
<main>
    <article>Math paper</article>
    <article>Politics paper</article>
    <article>CS paper</article>
</main>
<section>
    <h1>Filter</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Math
        <li>Politics
        <li>Computer Science
    </ul>
</section>
```

Should I use section as I am using in the example? Or a Aside will be better choice? Or a section inside a aside? or a plain old div? or maybe a nav?

That *section* will be styled like a sidebar, but that doesn’t matter... right? It is very difficult for me to determine what is a tangentially related content and what's not.

Comment: A section is for a part of the page or a part of an article.  An article is for a story or such ("article" -- I think you've got that). An aside is like a brief commentary or analogy or something else related to the article or section.  Your filter, however, is none of those -- it's more of a menu which allows the user to execute a command (ofc menu and command aren't in any browsers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question comes close to being primarily about opinions and subjective interpretations, but it is relatively clear that the filter is navigation of a kind (it lets the user access some content by filtering out other content). So it would best be marked up as [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element), if you wish to code by HTML5 principles.

On the other hand, this is not to be worried about, really. The choice hardly has any practical impact now. In the future, some browsers or assistive software may allow the user to skip `nav` elements or, as the case may be, access them e.g. with a special command. This supports the idea of using `nav` here. To help assistive software treat the element as navigational even if the software does not recognize `nav` “semantics” yet, the `role` attribute is advised:

```
<nav role="navigation">
```

Comment: I like the pragmatic approach :)